# What is the minimum current I need to supply to a Spartan-6 pin in order to register a high signal?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, spartan

Digging around in the [spartan-6 DC and switching characteristics guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/data_sheets/ds162.pdf), I can't find what I'm looking for.

Also no absolute max sync/source current ratings for the user IO pins. Looking at the dev board schematic, I know that 2mA is safe based on the resistor values used, but isn't this in a datasheet somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the input is set to CMOS mode (you can choose between LVTTL and CMOS amongst others) then almost zero current is required (e.g. a few uA max)
All you really need to be concerned about is the minimum logic high *voltage*, which will be stated in the datasheet (probably ~3V for 3.3V supply).

The source/drive current for output pins can be set from 2mA to 24mA (see pg.23 and beyond)

Being pretty complex devices, there are [quite a few documents](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/spartan-6.htm) related to these FPGAs, make sure you grab them all and spend a whle reading through them. If you still can't find a particular spec, ask on the Xilinx forum, I've found you get pretty helpful and quick responses there.

Comment: I'm aware of the drive currents for the output pins, and am quite familiar with the xilinx documentation, however, how do you know it's just a few uA, where is that information published? I also need to pick resistor values for the circuitry surrounding the FPGA, and I need to know exactly how much current I can and can't push into one of those pins. The absolute ratings table on the DC switching datasheet doesn't mention any current ratings.

Comment: If I'm asking the wrong question and it turns out these values are insignificant, and so not published, then I'm fully open to learning why these numbers don't matter. If you can explain why I shouldn't be looking for max current ratings, then cool.

Comment: Also, what about other modes? LVTTL?

Comment: @StaceyAnneRieck: You don't "push" current into an input pin, it draws current based on the voltage you place on it. The parameters you're looking for are called "input leakage current", and are given in Table 4 on page 5 as I_ref, I_L, and I_HS.

Comment: OK, so then I don't understand what the circuitry behind the FPGA pin looks like. I was assuming that the pin is a drain, with no current limitation, and that I control the input current by my choice of current limiting resistor.

Comment: Found Thevenin equivilent termination resistance in same table. facepalm. thanks guys. So inherently, my max input current is going to be input voltage/termination resistor. Question: This means that I could theoretically connect 2.5V to an input directly? (not that I would!) Or is there something else I should know about?

Comment: @StaceyAnneRieck: Sure, you can connect 2.5V directly to an input; you just need to make sure that the supply voltage on the I/O bank in question is also 2.5V (or more).